# NPM dependency conflict in React @types/react

Tags: reactjs, npm, testing-library

I'm struggling to understand what is the actual conflict here. It seems the same library `@testing-library/react-hooks@8.0.1` requires both `@types/react@"^16.9.0 || ^17.0.0"` and `@types/react@18.2.18`?

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @testing-library/react-hooks@8.0.1
npm ERR! Found: @types/react@18.2.18
npm ERR! node_modules/@types/react
npm ERR!   @types/react@"*" from @types/hoist-non-react-statics@3.3.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@types/hoist-non-react-statics
npm ERR!     @types/hoist-non-react-statics@"^3.3.1" from react-redux@8.0.5
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-redux
npm ERR!       react-redux@"^8.0.5" from the root project
npm ERR!   @types/react@"*" from @types/react-dom@18.2.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@types/react-dom
npm ERR!     @types/react-dom@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@14.0.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!       dev @testing-library/react@"^14.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peerOptional @types/react-dom@"^16.8 || ^17.0 || ^18.0" from react-redux@8.0.5
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-redux
npm ERR!       react-redux@"^8.0.5" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!   4 more (@types/react-router, @types/react-router-dom, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional @types/react@"^16.9.0 || ^17.0.0" from @testing-library/react-hooks@8.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@testing-library/react-hooks
npm ERR!   dev @testing-library/react-hooks@"^8.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @types/react@17.0.62
npm ERR! node_modules/@types/react
npm ERR!   peerOptional @types/react@"^16.9.0 || ^17.0.0" from @testing-library/react-hooks@8.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react-hooks
npm ERR!     dev @testing-library/react-hooks@"^8.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
```

Comment: Nothing there says it needs 18.2.18; that's what you _have_. It needs ^16.9 || ^17, hence the conflict.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I see, this report is a bit confusing in my hopinion..